# How can I refine an orbital plan to get from one planet to another?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design

Suppose I have an idea for a better way to go from planet A to planet B. What do I need to do to determine the delta-V required and efficiency in terms of reducing necessary shielding mass on the vehicle that actually travels? What software should I use to simulate the orbits and figure out the windows? Are there any guides to this process?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it overlaps a bit, but I'm still curious about what software I need to get answers to questions like delta-V requirements and designing it myself instead of reading the answer.

Comment: An object with a 2 year period might pass by earth every 2nd year at perihelion. But it would very seldom pass by Mars. For regular and frequent fly bys of both planets, it needs to be resonant with both planets. Some strings to Google: Aldrin Cyclers  Visit 1 Cyclers  Visit 2 Cyclers. The Aldrin Cycler has an aphelion out in the Main Belt. Delta V for Cycler to Mars taxi would be 9 km/s if memory serves. The Visit 1 and 2 cyclers are more Hohmann like and take less delta V. But their fly bys are less frequent.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate, altough I think the premise is flawed because an object in a 2:1 resonance orbit with Earth will hardly ever actually *encounter* Mars when it passes through Mar's orbit: mars will be elsewhere. There would be other problems too. Anyway, I feel this question is fine if it's primarily about 2:1 resonance orbits, rather than interplanetary ferries.